# How to get iDevices's Serial Number from NSURLRequest/NSURLConnections (which be sent by an iDevices) by PHP

Tags: php, iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I have an iOS app send an `NSURLRequest`/`NSURLConnections` to PHP Webserver. How can i detect iDevices's Serial Number which sent `NSURLRequest`/`NSURLConnections` to my PHP Webserver? Anybody can help me? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSString *uid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

All the Best.

Comment: Why you want to use php? if you want to store/use the device udid in the webserver ,the detect is using my code and pass it as argument to the php url.

Comment: If pass UniqueIdentifier as argument to the php url, i'll don't known it come from iDevices which have that UniqueIdentifier. I want to make sure it come from exactly iDevice which have that UniqueIdentifier. Can you tell me how to do it :)